Fastest implementation of a Priority Queue with frequent inserts
What priority queue implementation has the best run time when you insert twice as frequently as delete min.
I was lookin at this question Which priority queue is faster in practice? but the OP cared more about get min than inserts. I did some digging too on Fibonacci heaps but found that they are only better when you have less inserts than get mins. Brodal queues also seem fast but I'm not sure if they are efficient in practice.
Some implementations:

Binary
Skew
Leftist
Binomial
Skew binomial
2–3 heap
Bottom-up skew
Pairing
Rank-pairing
Fibonacci
Strict Fibonacci
Brodal

Or maybe even bucketing?
What would be the fastest in practice? Thanks.

What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

So far I've implemented a binary tree implementation but I was wondering if there was a better way. Not really a problem where I have an error but I am looking for optimization.

@computer_goblin You said you "implemented a binary tree implementation." Do you mean that you implemented a binary heap? Or that you implemented a heap in a binary search tree? Have you tried Python's heapq?

The question may not fit to SO scope.
But to respond you, for a priority queue with frequent inserts (twice as often as delete min), a pairing heap is likely the best choice.
Pairing heap has O(1) time for inserts and O(log n) for delete min.
Fibonacci heaps also perform well with frequent inserts, they can introduce more overhead in practice.

I haven't been on SO a lot lately so I'm not sure how the guidelines have changed but I  would love to know if there is a more specific community where asking this question would be better! Also, lots of heap implementations have similar big O's but in practice have you found any to have a faster run time?

@computer_goblin, SO is about codes than advice. However, I did not close your question (not even have that privilege).

Note that the O(log n) time for delete-min is amortized. That O(log n) delete-min assumes a fairly even balance between insertions and removals. That said, I agree that pairing heap looks to be a likely candidate. And, as you imply, Fibonacci heap looks good on paper but in practice it doesn't outperform binary heap or pairing heap in the general case. I don't expect it would outperform pairing heap in this case, either.
